# Append comma after each value and then show in single line

Tags: excel, notepad++

I have around 15000 rows in my excel like

```
ATM-12345678976-0001
ATM-12345675555-0002
ATM-12345675555-0003
```

and so on......

```
I wanted to append comma after each value and then want in a single like like below :
ATM-12345678976-0001,ATM-12345675555-0002, ATM-12345675555-0003,.......
```

How i can achieve this ?

Comment: You could save your excel as a (tab delimited) text file and open it in notepad. Then search for `\s\n(?=.)` and replace with `, `

Comment: Thank you, it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R`
- Replace with: `,`  # a comma and a space
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]